# Disable verified label in subprojects

Tags: gerrit

I am setting up a gerrit server. I want some projects to have the verified label, where a jenkins build, if successful will set the verified flag. This works fine for me.

I also have some projects which doesn't need a jenkins build to verify. So for this I want to disable the Verified flag and the changes be submit-able on +2 code review.

From gerrit documentation, adding an empty label in parent will remove the label for child. How exactly to do this? I created a intermediate project. But on trying to add an empty label

> [label "Verified"]

I am getting the below error.

```
remote: Processing changes: refs: 1, done    
remote: error: Invalid project configuration:
remote: error:   project.config: Invalid defaultValue "0" for label "Verified"
To ssh://<gerrit server>:29418/NoVerify
 ! [remote rejected] meta/config -> refs/meta/config (invalid project configuration)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://<gerrit server>:29418/NoVerify'
```

How can I solve this? Or if I am adding the empty label wrong, how to add it properly.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add the following in .projectconfig on meta/config branch. This will skip "verified +1" and enable the submit.

```
[label "Verified"]
defaultValue = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. The other solutions didn't work.
However, setting the function to [NoOp](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/config-labels.html#label_function) in the `project.config` made the label go away.

```
[label "Verified"]
    function = NoOp
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following string after `[label "Verified"]` section:

`value =  0 No score`